# Show the beginning of a long string in a QML TextInput instead of the end

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a TextInput QML (Qt 5.12.2) control wrapped in a Rectangle item (for styling) that I am pre-populating with a string. Sometimes that string may be longer than the max width of the TextInput. When that happens the text in the text input shows the end of the string like this:

[image: TextInput with end of string displayed]

However, I would like the text in the TextInput to display from the start of the string like this:

[image: TextInput with start of string displayed]

Here is a sample that reproduces this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Rectangle {
        border.width: 1
        border.color: 'black'
        height: childrenRect.height
        width: 600
        clip: true
        TextInput {
            width: parent.width
            text: "1. The quick bown dog jumps over the lazy dog. 2. The quick bown dog jumps over the lazy dog. 3. The quick bown dog jumps over the lazy dog. 4. The quick bown dog jumps over the lazy dog."
        }
    }
}
```

I tried setting [autoScroll](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#autoScroll-prop) to false which does make it display the way I want but also disables the ability for the user to scroll the text if they want to read the end of it. Is there something else I can to do fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can the [ensureVisible](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#ensureVisible-method) method:

```
TextInput {
    id: input
    width: parent.width
    text: "1. The quick bown dog jumps over the lazy dog. 2. The quick bown dog jumps over the lazy dog. 3. The quick bown dog jumps over the lazy dog. 4. The quick bown dog jumps over the lazy dog."
    Component.onCompleted: input.ensureVisible(0)
}
```